# How can I get the MAX of a range of cells based on whether the cells meet a criteria?

Tags: excel

My example data set is

```
+-------+--------+--------+  
| TEAM  | NAME   | SCORE  |
+-------+--------+--------+
| ACE   | Sara   |  15    |
| ACE   | Mike   |  10    |
| ACE   | Lucy   |  20    |
| BEE   | Jason  |  10    |
| BEE   | Quinn  |  5     |
+-------+--------+--------+
```

What I want to do is if a TEAM has 3 or more Players, then label the player with the highest score 'captain' and everyone else 'crew'. If a TEAM has less than 3 Players, then everyone would be labeled 'crew'.
I've used a `=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A,A2)>=3, TRUE, FALSE` see whether the TEAM qualifies as having 3 or more. I also know I'd have to use the =MAX() function to see who has the highest score. I'm just not sure how to limit it based on the team and how to adequately label each row.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A2)>2,INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($C$2:$C$6)/(($C$2:$C$6=AGGREGATE(14,6,$C$2:$C$6/($A$2:$A$6=A2),1))*($A$2:$A$6=A2)),1))=B2),"Captain","Crew")
```

[image]